# Source Control Explorer Only for TFVC repos

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

In Azure DevOps, I have a project. I called it **SourceControl** as shown in the picture below. In this project I have created multiple repos (just for learning as am exploring).

[image: Azure DevOps Multiple Repos in a project]

Now from Visual Studio Team Explorer, I clicked the green plug icon, to get to Manage Connections, and then I clicked connect to project.

[image: Manage Connections in Vs Team Explorer]

When I connect to $/SourceControl, a Team foundation version control system, then the source control explorer works fine.

[image: Source Control Explorer with Tfvc system connected]

But when I connect to any git system, then the source control explorer shows disconnected.

[image: Source Control Explorer with Git system connected]

I am not able to comprehend, does not the source control explorer work with gits systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the source control explorer is **only** for TFVC.

In git, you clone the whole repo, you don't need the explorer for mapping, workspaces etc.

You can find the official docs about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/use-source-control-explorer-manage-files-under-version-control?view=azure-devops):

> Q: Why do I see this error message: "Team Foundation Server is not
>   your current Source Control plug-in. Click here to set the current
>   Source Control plug-in"?
>
> A: You might have connected to a Git repository in your project. Use
>   Team Explorer and Solution Explorer to manage your files in Git repos.